# Jest / Enzyme - mock async function in lifecycle method

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to unit test my React component with Jest. My tests are passing but I get TypeError because of console.error() in try/catch. I think my mock isn't set properly but I tried do it async withour any results. I appreciate any tips.

> console.error components/App.js:91
>         TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchPoints' of undefined
>             at App.fetchPoints (D:\\components\App.js:87:48)
>             at tryCatch (D:\\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
>             at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (D:\\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:296:22)
>             at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (D:\\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
>             at step (D:\\components\App.js:38:191)
>             at D:\\components\App.js:38:437
>             at new Promise ()
>             at App. (D:\\components\App.js:38:99)
>             at App.componentDidMount (D:\\components\App.js:155:30)
>             at D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:262:25
>             at measureLifeCyclePerf (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:73:12)
>             at D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactCompositeComponent.js:261:11
>             at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\CallbackQueue.js:74:22)
>             at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.close (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactTestReconcileTransaction.js:34:26)
>             at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.closeAll (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\Transaction.js:207:25)
>             at ReactTestReconcileTransaction.perform (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\Transaction.js:154:16)
>             at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactTestMount.js:67:27)
>             at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\Transaction.js:141:20)
>             at Object.batchedUpdates (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:60:26)
>             at Object.batchedUpdates (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactUpdates.js:95:27)
>             at Object.render (D:\\node_modules\react-test-renderer\lib\ReactTestMount.js:126:18)
>             at Object.create (D:\\components__tests__\App.test.js:26:31)
>             at Object.asyncJestTest (D:\\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\jasmine_async.js:108:37)
>             at resolve (D:\\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queue_runner.js:56:12)
>             at new Promise ()
>             at mapper (D:\\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queue_runner.js:43:19)
>             at promise.then (D:\\node_modules\jest-jasmine2\build\queue_runner.js:87:41)
>             at 
>             at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

App.test.js

I tried to use mount() and fetchPoints to return Promise.resolve().

```js
import React from 'react';
    import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
    import { shallow, configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
    import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15';
    import { App } from '../App';
    
    configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
    
    describe('App', () => {
        let wrapper;
        const apiMockActions = {
            fetchPoints : jest.fn()
        };
    
        beforeEach(() => {
            wrapper = shallow(<App actions={apiMockActions} />);
        });
     
        it('should call fetchPoints in #componentDidMount', () => {
            return wrapper.instance().componentDidMount().then(() => {
                expect(apiMockActions.fetchPoints).toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
        });
    
    });
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import * as api from '../actions/api';
    import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
    
    export class App extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                data: []
            }  
        }
        async componentDidMount() {
            try {
                let res = await this.props.actions.fetchPoints();
                //this.setState({ data: res });
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="col-md-12 app__div">      
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            data: state.points
        };
    }
    
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            actions: bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, api), dispatch)
        };
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
        "ag-grid": "^14.2.0",
        "ag-grid-react": "^14.2.0",
        "axios": "^0.16.2",
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "eslint": "^5.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
        "lodash": "^4.15.0",
        "moment": "^2.19.3",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "rc-time-picker": "^2.4.1",
        "react": "^15.6.2",
        "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
        "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.2",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
        "react-color": "^2.14.0",
        "react-datalist": "^4.0.0",
        "react-datepicker": "^0.29.0",
        "react-dom": "^15.6.2",
        "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
        "react-dropzone": "^3.13.4",
        "react-grid-layout": "^0.15.3",
        "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
        "react-notification-system": "^0.2.16",
        "react-notify": "^2.0.1",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
        "react-timepicker": "^1.3.1",
        "react-toggle-display": "^2.2.0",
        "redux": "^3.7.2",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-promise-middleware": "^4.4.2",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "section-iterator": "^2.0.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-jest": "^23.4.0",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.2",
        "babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.13.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "chalk": "^2.3.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1.1",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
        "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.6",
        "jest": "^23.4.1",
        "jest-cli": "^23.4.1",
        "parallel-webpack": "^1.5.0",
        "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^1.11.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.2",
        "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "webpack": "^4.16.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8"
      },
```

Comment: it looks like you are using an older version of `react`, can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spies and stubs should be created for each test:

```
let apiMockActions;

beforeEach(() => {
  apiMockActions = {
    fetchPoints : jest.fn()
  };
});
```

Lifecycles are enabled by default in Enzyme 3 and higher, so calling `componentDidMount` manually results in calling it twice. They [can be disabled](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#lifecycle-methods) in order to chain a promise from `componentDidMount`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<App actions={apiMockActions} />, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
});
```

Returned promise value can be mocked with `mockResolvedValue`:

```
it('should call fetchPoints in #componentDidMount', async () => {
    const points = [...];
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    apiMockActions.fetchPoints.mockResolvedValue(points);
    await instance.componentDidMount();
    expect(apiMockActions.fetchPoints).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(instance.state.data).toEqual({ data: points });
});
```

Comment: Still get this console message. All tests passed.
console.log components/App.js:38
      Cannot read property 'fetchPoints' of undefined

Comment: I updated the answer. However, I'm not sure how `actions` can be undefined if you included `beforeEach` that was suggested. I'd suggest to debug your code and make sure that `apiMockActions` is an object in `(<App actions={apiMockActions} />`.

Comment: It's all good. 
`console.log(typeof instance.props.actions) outputs: object` 
fetchPoints function is defined in instance also. 
When I remove console.error(e) statement from try/catch it doesn't output 'undefined'. I'm courious why catch block is invoked because I defined resolved value.

Comment: When I defined mockRejectedValue('403') it outputs '403' in console as I expected. fetchPoints undefiend not appear. However I still don't know why fetchPoints() function is invoked in catch block when I don't define mockRejectedValue. I think it should output 'error' is undefined. I'll do some research in Jest docs. Thanks for help!

Comment: It outputs undefined because `this.props.actions` is undefined and results in error. I don't think that this has something to do with mockRejectedValue, a mock was set up incorrectly in OP but it wouldn't result in this error. The code you provided cannot explain it. Since `actions` is clearly provided as `shallow(<App actions={apiMockActions} />, ...)`, this possibly means that `App` is instantiated somewhere else. Also double check that `apiMockActions` is an object where you call `shallow`.

Comment: It turns out that I have one more test in App.test.js file.
` const tree = renderer.create(<App actions={apiMockActions} />);`
I didn't pass actions prop to it. My fault :) At least I learn something about mocking :) Anyway thanks for help :)